# codeigniter image library does it really work?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, gd

Image upload properly but not resizing the image:
Here is the html:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/image_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
    </form>
```

here is the controller:

```
public function image_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']       = './upload';
    $config['allowed_types']     = 'jpg|png|jpeg';

    $config['max_size']          = 2000;
    $config['min_size']          = 100;

    $config['max_width']         = 1024;
    $config['min_width']         = 400;

    $config['max_height']        = 1000;
    $config['min_height']        = 400;

    $config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("image"))
    {
       echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }else{
        $data[] = $this->upload->data();

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $data[0]["full_path"];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']         = 600;
        $config['height']       = 800;

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
```

output:
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.
JPG images are not supported.(when i upload jpg file says, when upload png file then also says not supported).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by installing GD library in my linux system.